# How do I print a value from a custom user field on page.tpl?

Tags: users, 7

I have a integer field connected to my users that I would like to print out in the header of my site. I would like to display the value of the field for the user that is currently logged in. When I do print dpm($user) it shows me information about the currently logged in user, but not any of the custom profile fields associated with them.

Comment: How are you connecting your custom field to the user, What module are you using and what Drupal version are you running?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I am running Drupal 7, and just have a integer field on my users. No module, just a core field.

Answer (score 2):

First I want to thank @mototribe and @Kimi for helping me figure this out.  I was able to get access to my field by putting

```
<?php 
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$MYVARIABLE = $user_fields->field_MYFIELD;
?>
```

at the start of my page.tpl.  Then I had to print it out by adding this to my page  `<?php print $MYVARIABLE['und'][0]['value'];?>`

Answer (score 1):

Add a THEME_process_page function to your template.php (replace THEME with the name of your theme):

```
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$variables['nickname'] = '';
$nickname = $user->field_nickname;
if($nickname) {
  $variables['nickname'] = $nickname['und'][0]['safe_value'];
}
```

Now you can add this to your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $nickname ?>
```

Comment: When I try and use this method, I get errors

Comment: I am assuming that by $nickname you mean my  field?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

> I have a integer field connected to my users that I would like to print

This is somewhat confusing, have you used some module like content_profile or you have altered the users table perhaps .. ?

Any ways, the $user object wont get your "integer field" directly as the user object prints all the data from the users table itself.

If your integer field is part of a node that user has created, try

```
global $user;
$nid = db_result(db_query( /*This is where you get the nid of the node*/ ));
$node = node_load($nid);
//then we print the field you want 
print $node->integer_field;  
// or if its not a node then simple print $variable; will do.
```

The above code needs to go in a block or some tpl that will print it in your header.

Please give more info if the above is not correct...

Comment: Thanks. To clarify what I'm looking for, I just need a way to print out a custom user field. I'm using Drupal 7 and I made a field connected to my users that is of type "integer".